# Loop and renderText in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to loop through a dataframe and print output in R shiny. Here is the stand alone example for the code which works fine. But as soon as I use `renderText` in shiny its blank output.What am I doing wrong here.

```
renderText({


emp.data <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c (1:5), 
  emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary"),
  salary = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25), 

  start_date = as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2013-09-23", "2014-11-15", "2014-05-11",
                         "2015-03-27")),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
for (row in 1:nrow(emp.data)) {
  name <- emp.data[row, "emp_name"]
  salary  <- emp.data[row, "salary"]



 print( paste(" Employee ", name ,"has a total of ",salary," dollars"))

}   
          }


    })
```

I am using `textOutput` in UI

Comment: You can't render a data.frame as text, render a table instead

Comment: I have the same issue when I use renderUI. All I want to do was show the table outputs as sentences

Comment: I would save all phrases as rows of a df pull them using either pull() from dplyr or the $ operator, then print render this text variable, you can't render a print in shinny, prints escape to your enviroment not shinny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
library(tidyverse)


renderText({

emp.data <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c (1:5), 
  emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary"),
  salary = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25), 

  start_date = as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2013-09-23", "2014-11-15", "2014-05-11",
                         "2015-03-27")),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df_text <- c()
for (row in 1:nrow(emp.data)) {
  name <- emp.data[row, "emp_name"]
  salary  <- emp.data[row, "salary"]
  df_text[row] <- paste(" Employee ", name ,"has a total of ",salary," dollars")
}  

  df_text

  })
```